# Как передать значение float в строку в Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, строки

Мне нужно в строку `NSString` передать некоторое значение `float`. Какой заместитель нужно использовать вместо `%f`, чтобы код (ниже) работал корректно?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        float x = 323.13;
        NSString *text1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Переменная x = " @"%.f" , "x"];
        NSLog(text1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:`переменная x = 0`

Нужно, чтоб было `переменная x = 323.13`
Что для этого нужно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если известно, что будет два знака после запятой то вот так:

```
float x = 323.13;
NSString *text1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Переменная x = %.2f" , x];
NSLog(text1);
```

Comment: Спасибо. А то три часа убил в поисках.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ Max Mikheyenko корректен и достаточен для данного случая, однако, для отображения подобного числа в интерфейсе в продакшене не очень подходит.
В реальном приложении лучше использовать класс [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/), который может быть легко настроен, а так же учитывает текущую локаль при конвертировании числа в строку и обратно (например в русской локали в качестве делителя дробной части используется запятая, а не точка).

Тогда указанный пример превратится в следующий:

```
float x = 323.13;
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = <Создаём и настраиваем форматтер>
NSString *text1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Переменная x = %@" , [formatter stringFromNumber:@(x)]];
NSLog(text1);
```

И вывод в лог будет с учётом выбранной локали (системной или установленной в форматтере).